# Multipart/related upload using BackgroundUploader in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, multipart, background-transfer

I want to upload a file using **Multipart/related** Content-Type via **BackgroundUploader** in windows 8.1

My code is as follows

```
BackgroundUploader uploader = new BackgroundUploader();
uploader.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz");
uploader.Method = "POST";

// Create upload content
List<BackgroundTransferContentPart> parts = new List<BackgroundTransferContentPart>();

// File metadata
var part = new BackgroundTransferContentPart();
part.SetHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
part.SetText(file.DisplayName);
parts.Add(part);

// File
// Here file is of type StorageFile
part = new BackgroundTransferContentPart();
part.SetHeader("Content-Type", file.ContentType);
part.SetFile(file);
parts.Add(part);

UploadOperation upload = await uploader.CreateUploadAsync(new Uri("upload_url",UriKind.Absolute), parts);

await upload.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.token);  // cts is CancellationTokenSource
```

However, when I run this code I get an Exception saying

> WinRT information: 'boundary': If the 'Content-Type' header is set,
>   the boundary cannot be empty and must match the boundary set in the
>   'Content-Type' header.

What is wrong/missing in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing a list of content parts, you don't need to set the Conent-Type header. It's set automatically.

However if you insist in doing so, try:

```
uploader.SetRequestHeader(
    "Content-Type", 
    "multipart/form-data; boundary=\"foo_bar_baz\"");
```

**UPDATE:**

Try using the `CreateUploadAsync` overload that takes four parameters, where the fourth parameter is the boundary. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh923975

Comment: Using multipart/form-data also gives same error. Since, server demands multipart/related, I can't omit it

Answer (score 1):

If you use the CreateUploadAsync with four parameters then the following might be helpful:

```
var uploader = new BackgroundUploader();
uploader.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-3770FB3C-534D-4E6B-9BE0-392FDA960F7B");

var upload = await uploader.CreateUploadAsync(uri, parts, "form-data", "0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-3770FB3C-534D-4E6B-9BE0-392FDA960F7B");

await upload.StartAsync();
```

Set the boundary in the "SetRequestHeader" without "" (quotes).
Set the same boundary later as the last parameter of CreateUploadAsync.